# JSON: JsonMappingException while try to deserialize object with null values

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I try to deserialize object that contains null-properties and have the `JsonMappingException`.

**What I do:**

```
String actual = "{\"@class\" : \"PersonResponse\"," +
                "  \"id\" : \"PersonResponse\"," +
                "  \"result\" : \"Ok\"," +
                "  \"message\" : \"Send new person object to the client\"," +
                "  \"person\" : {" +
                "    \"id\" : 51," +
                "    \"firstName\" : null}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(new StringReader(json), PersonResponse.class); //EXCEPTION!
```

**BUT**: if to throw away `"firstName = null"` property - all works fine!
I mean pass the next string:

```
String test = "{\"@class\" : \"PersonResponse\"," +
                "  \"id\" : \"PersonResponse\"," +
                "  \"result\" : \"Ok\"," +
                "  \"message\" : \"Send new person object to the client\"," +
                "  \"person\" : {" +
                "    \"id\" : 51}}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(new StringReader(json), PersonResponse.class); //ALL WORKS FINE!
```

**Question**: 
How to avoid this exception or to pledge Jackson ignore null-values during serialization?

**Throws:**

***Message:***

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MessageJsonException:
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
  N/A (through reference chain: person.Create["person"]->Person["firstName"])
```

***cause:***

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MessageJsonException:
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
  N/A (through reference chain: prson.Create["person"]->Person["firstName"])
```

***cause:*** `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't want to serialize `null` values, you can use the following setting (during serialization):

```java
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

But the `NullPointerException` you get during deserialization seems suspicious to me (Jackson should ideally be able to handle `null` values in the serialized output). Could you post the code corresponding to the `PersonResponse` class?

Comment: hah. I also have collections in my person-class, so I need to set Include.NOT_EMPTY. Thanks!!!

Comment: Where should I put the objectMapper? within controller? or in the POJO bean?  thanks....

Comment: It's NON_EMPTY not NOT_EMPTY

Answer (score 57):

Sometimes this problem occurs when accidentally using a primitive type as return type of the getter of a non-primitive field:

```
public class Item
{
    private Float value;

    public float getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Float value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}
```

Notice the "float" instead of "Float" for the getValue()-method, this can lead to a Null Pointer Exception, even when you have added

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: Yes. And note that this is because of implicit coercion in `getValue()`, which is basically doing "return value.floatValue()" to get primitive -- hence NPE. Caller has no way of avoiding that, or knowing there is such a problem (unless it went and decoded bytecode etc).

Comment: You sir saved my day :) I had a Boolean value, but accidently in the getter had it as a boolean and it was null :D

Comment: This was it. I also had a `Boolean` and a method `boolean get...()`.

Comment: And my issue was that the getter / setter was had a typo. After I recreated the getters and setters using Eclipse's tools, everything works

Comment: you are a savior. I was debugging it and analysing like a big issue and this was a simple mistake on my side. thanks so much :)

Comment: Thank you sir (another reason to use Kotlin in the future, which has a uniform type system) :)

Comment: After an hour of frustration i came upon this -- and voila!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue.

I just included a default constructor in the model class along with the other constructor with parameters.

It worked.

```
package objmodel;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class CarModel {

private String company;
private String model;
private String color;
private String power;


public CarModel() {
}

public CarModel(String company, String model, String color, String power) {
    this.company = company;
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.power = power;

}

@JsonDeserialize
public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

@JsonDeserialize
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

@JsonDeserialize
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

@JsonDeserialize
public String getPower() {
    return power;
}

public void setPower(String power) {
    this.power = power;
}
}
```

Comment: I also tried removing the annotations "@JsonDeserialize" and also removing the line 
objectmapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

It worked fine!!

Comment: Had to add super() in the default constructor to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add JsonProperty annotation to your attribute in TO class, as below

```
@JsonProperty
private String id;
```