# How to map JSON with nullable array properties to POJO using WildFly RestEasy

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, resteasy, wildfly, pojo

I have JSON

```
{
  "name": "volo",
  "friends": ["joe", "alex"]
}
```

and Java POJO

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  private Set<String> friends;

  //constructor, getters, setters
}
```

POST method:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createPerson(Person person) {
  //logic
}
```

This is work nice when POST or PUT request are coming and JSON is parsed to POJO, but when

```
"friends": null
```

WildFly RestEasy cannot parse JSON to POJO and Response with error is returned

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A (through reference chain: dk.systematic.beacon.workspace.WorkspaceInfo["friends"])
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this with some annotation or additional setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON: JsonMappingException while try to deserialize object with null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096589)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in setter method

Before fix:

```
public void setFriends(Set<String> friends) {
  this.friends = new HashSet<>(friends)
}
```

To fix just need to add validation

```
public void setFriends(Set<String> friends) {
  if (friends != null) {
    this.friends = new HashSet<>(friends)
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will help to avoid same mistakes for others.